# passing and using hash object in ActiveRecord's new method- Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Simple, quick, question.

How can i pass a hash or associative array through my view/javascript to rails controller.
In the contoller i want to use hash object in ActiveRecord's new method

some thing like this

```
 hash = {}
 hash = params[data]
 Task.new(hash)
```

I can pass and read individual fields, but i am looking for a better way.
Thnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work, actually. Did you try it out?

Here's a one-liner:

```
Task.new params[:task]
```

You should be aware that arbitrary values can be passed by the client, creating a potential mass assignment security issue. Make sure to define mass assignable fields with `attr_accessible`.

Comment: yes its correct. my bad. actually my hash was incorrect. thnx.

Comment: @mashit, I'm glad it helped you. Please don't forget to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)!